# Searching for duplicate entries with PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a spot of trouble with a bit of code meant to find duplicates of a name along with the platform. This will also be adapted to find unique IDs later on.

So for example, if there is a server named "Apple" on the Xbox and you try to insert a record with the name "Apple" with the same platform it will reject it. However, another platform with the same name is allowed, such as "Apple" with PS3.

I've tried coming up with ideas and searching for answers, but I'm kind of in the dark as to what is the best way to go about checking for duplicates.

So far this is what I have:

```
$nameDuplicate_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE name=':name' AND platform=':platform'");
$nameDuplicate_sql->bindValue(':name', $name);
$nameDuplicate_sql->bindValue(':platform', $platform);
$nameDuplicate_sql->execute();
```

I've tried a bunch of different solutions, some from here, others from the PHP's manual and etc. None appear to work though.

I'm trying to stick with PDO, however, this is one instance where I cannot figure out where to turn. If this was in mysql_* I probably could just use mysql_affected_rows, but with PDO I have no clue. rowCount seemed promising, but it always returns 0 since this is neither an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

Oh, and I've tried the SQL statement in phpMyAdmin and it works; I tried it with a simple name/platform and it found rows properly.

If anyone can help me out here I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows  affected by a SELECT statement. 
>       Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the  same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned. 
>       Your application can then perform the correct action.

Comment: My only qualms with this is that I'd have to escape it, so that's why I'd rather lean towards a prepared statement. Would it be possible to use a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with a prepared statement instead of query?

I really don't trust myself with escaping.

Comment: Actually I've tried this with a prepared statement and it works. I used fetchColumn with SELECT COUNT(*) as you've mentioned and it reliably returns the rows that match the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for duplicates, why not just enforce it on the database table directly? Create a composite key that will prohibit entries being made if they are already there?

```
CREATE TABLE servers (
    serverName varchar(50),
    platform varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (serverName, platform)
)
```

This way, you will *never* get duplicates, and it also allows you to use the mysql `insert... on duplicate key update...` syntax which sounds like it might be rather handy for you.

If you already have a Primary Key on it or you don't want to make a new table, you can use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE servers DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(serverName, platform);
```

Edit: A primary key is either a single row or a number of rows that *have* to have unique data in them. A single row cannot have the same value twice, but a composite key (which is what I am suggesting here) means that between the two columns, the same data cannot appear.

In this case, what you want to do, add in a server name and have it associated with a platform - the table will let you add in as many rows containing the same server name - as long as each one has a unique platform associated with it - and vice versa, you can have a platform listed as many times as you like, as long as all the server names are unique.

If you try to insert a record where the same servername/platform combination exists, the database simply won't let you do it. There is another golden benefit though. Due to this key constraint - mysql allows a special type of query to be used. It is the `insert... on duplicate key update` syntax. That means if you try to insert the same data twice (ie, database says no) you can catch it and update the row you already have in the table. For example:

You have a row with `serverName=Fluffeh` and it is on `platform=Boosh` but you don't know about it right now, so you try to insert a record with the intention of updating the server IP address.

Normally you would simply write something like this:

```
insert into servers (serverName, platform, IPAddress) 
values ('$serverName', '$platform', '$IPAddy')
```

But with a nice primary key identified you can do this:

```
insert into servers (serverName, platform, IPAddress) 
values ('$serverName', '$platform', '$IPAddy') 
on duplicate key update set IPAddress='$IPAddy';
```

The second query will insert the row with all the data if it doesn't exist already. If it doesm, Bam! it will update the IP Address of the server which was your intention all along.

Comment: I never knew anything like this existed. How does this work exactly?

Comment: Well i wouldnt make it the primary key.. i would use a second unique key.

Comment: @prodigitalson Yeah, the primary could be a surrogate key based on this unique key - but lets not make the matter too complicated for a chap who is just learning about unique keys and enforcing data integrity :)

Comment: @Fluffeh Wow. That's a lot of information. I never knew anything like this existed. As you've stated though, there's no need to get more complicated. But this will definitely come in handy later on when I will have to create a control panel of sorts.

Comment: @CaseyWeed Well, as prodigitalson states, using a surrogate key might be a good idea if you want to link to this from other tables (saves having to store redundant information in multiple tables) but one step at a time.

Comment: @Fluffeh Thanks for the information regardless. That will probably save me a lot of time later on.

Comment: No worries, I love to answer questions that might be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and find out that I am indeed helping nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes from your query on the parameter tokens... they will be quoted once they are bound... thats part of the reason for a prepared statement.

```
$nameDuplicate_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE name= :name AND platform= :platform");
```

Comment: Also you should use a count query here as Sel suggested.