# Use PDO to check for data duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, verification

I've looked at other questions on this but they won't work for me.

I want to check if a user has already logged in, using the value `steamid`. If they have, display their info, if they haven't, make a new account in the database. Here is what I have now:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

if($dbh){
echo "Connected successfully";
}
include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT steam_id FROM user WHERE steam_id = :steam_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':steam_id', $steamprofile['steamid']);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    echo "User already exists!";
}else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (display_name, user_url, steam_id, profil_image) 
    VALUES ('$steamprofile[personaname]', '$steamprofile[profileurl]', $steamprofile[steamid]), '$steamprofile[avatar]'";

    /*
    if ($dbh->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $dbh->error;
}
*/
}
```

As of this code, the only return is "connected successfully". No new data is added to the (empty) user database.

If I uncommented the last block, I get the output:

> "Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$error in
>   F:\Bitnami\htdocs\Dreamweaver\freehtml5streets\index.php on line 48
>   Error: INSERT INTO user (display_name, user_url, steam_id,
>   profil_image) VALUES (//list of corresponding values of signed in
>   user).

Comment: turn on error reporting and `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Please refer this link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273664/searching-for-duplicate-entries-with-pdo][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273664/searching-for-duplicate-entries-with-pdo

Answer (score 2):

You get the error "Undefined Property" because "error" is not defined as a property of $dbh.  You probably meant "errorInfo" see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

By the way building up an SQL statement using raw input leaves you totally vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: The info added isn't chosen or edited by the user, it's taken automatically from their Steam account, so SQL injection shouldn't be possible, should it?

Also, with that last error commented out, when the code gets to adding the info to the database, it will run other code there (echo) but it doesn't add info to the database. Why won't the data get added?

Comment: @Mitch8910 As a rule of thumb, never trust user input, always assume that's malicious or at the very least unsafe, always use prepared statements with parameter where possible or use whitelist validation where parameters are inpossible (e.g. table or column names)

Comment: @STTLCU Thanks for the advice, though, by user input do you mean an area where the user can submit their own text in a field? If all a user signs into the website by clicking one button to allow the use of their account from another website, SQL injection shouldn't be possible should it? I know I should have probably made a new question thread for this.

Comment: "User input" is a broad term. Even a simple GET request with no parameters (Example: http://www.example.com/webpage.php) in my book is user input. Is the user allowed to see the webpage.php, or did he try to access a restricted url? Sure, no SQL injection can happen in this case, but the user input was still malicious or incorrect and must not be trusted.

Answer (score 2):

The error exception is because pdo error exception returns an array of getMessage, getCode and getFile see below and example of its implementation.

```
public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->mssql = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'Connection Error, Contact admin for assistance ' . $e);
/** You can access the error messages using $e->getMessage() for the exception error message. $->getCode() for the error code;  $e->getFile(); return the file path  **/
        }
    }

//From the exerpt of your code try this 
include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
        if (!empty($steamprofile['steamid'])) {
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) from user WHERE steam_id = :steam_id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':steam_id', $steamprofile['steamid']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        }
//Row will return false if there was no value
        if ($count == 0) {
            //insert new data
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user (display_name, user_url, steam_id, profil_image)
    VALUES ('$steamprofile[personaname]', '$steamprofile[profileurl]', $steamprofile[steamid]), '$steamprofile[avatar]'";
        } else {
            //User exist
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I seem so hopeless at this and can't get anything done, and I can't see where I'm going wrong. I'm sure your code is right, but I can't get it to work. It seems ridiculous for such a small amount of code but I may just need to find someone to pay to do it. I have gotten this far but I can't get this to work no-matter what I do, it's so frustrating..

Comment: @Mitch8910 you can alternatively run two queries. one to count first then if no results do an insert with the id. what do you think of this approach ? i can edit the answer quickly

Comment: @Mitch8910 check out the last code block and see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks for continuing to try. This is what my code looks like now : 
http://gyazo.com/8321b4a8ef9c8eede1ae14418e3f2572
Yet I'm getting an error:
http://gyazo.com/e36fd6c7b342b2d5e27015e008f6cce4

Comment: Use bindValue instead of bindParam and change the prepare statement
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) from user WHERE steam_id = :steam_id");
                $stmt->bindValue(':steam_id', $steamprofile['steamid']);

Comment: I'm not getting any errors now, thanks. But the data still isn't logging into the database, I think there must be something wrong with my line:

 $sql = "INSERT INTO user (display_name, user_url, steam_id, profil_image)
    VALUES ('$steamprofile[personaname]', '$steamprofile[profileurl]', $steamprofile[steamid]), '$steamprofile[avatar]'";

Comment: there is an error in your query try this Add echo on if ($count == 0) {
            //insert new data
echo('new entry');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user (display_name, user_url, steam_id, profil_image)
    VALUES ('$steamprofile[personaname]', '$steamprofile[profileurl]', $steamprofile[steamid]), '$steamprofile[avatar]')";
echo ($sql);
die();
        } else {
            //User exist
echo('User Exist');
        }

Comment: I have done that: http://gyazo.com/71eea0a43bb61186be97f968336388f3
When I test it it prints "New user", so I assume it has to be the code that adds the data.

Comment: Yes the query has an error, it doesnt have a closing bracket check this one out. if ($count == 0) { //insert new data echo('new entry'); $sql = "INSERT INTO user (display_name, user_url, steam_id, profil_image) VALUES ('$steamprofile[personaname]', '$steamprofile[profileurl]', $steamprofile[steamid]), '$steamprofile[avatar]')"; echo ($sql); die(); } else { //User exist echo('User Exist'); }

Comment: I see, the close bracket was after $steamprofile[steamid], not [avatar]. I fixed that, and have  echo ($sql); die(); after it, and it runs those lines of code properly. Test output: http://gyazo.com/7700adafa21a623e964849b9616072ee

But it's still not adding anything to the database. I'm not sure why that would be though. I have to go to work now, thanks so much for the help so far, I'll have to keep on trying when I get home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75375/discussion-between-chapskev-and-mitch8910).